# Optimal transport between Gaussian mixtures and their centers

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gaussian, optimal-transportation

I have a question about bounding the Wasserstein loss between a continuous Gaussian mixture and a discrete uniform distribution of its centers. In particular, let $P=\frac 1 k \sum_{i=1}^k \mathcal{N}(\theta_i,\sigma^2 I_d) $ be a $d$-dimensional Gaussian mixture and let $Q=\frac 1 k \sum_i \delta_{\theta_i}$ be a uniform discrete distribution on the set of centers $\{\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_k\}$. For the case of $p=2$, my goal is to obtain the tightest bound as follows:
$$
W_2(P,Q) \leq \text{some function of } (\sigma,d)
$$

My attempt: Let $X=Z+\theta_D$ be a random variable where $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2 I_d)$ and $D\sim \mathsf{Unif}(\{1,\ldots,k\})$. Now define the random variable $Y=\theta_D$. Clearly $X \sim P$ and $Y\sim Q$. Then using the definition of $W_2$, we obtain that
$$
W_2(P,Q) \leq \sqrt{\mathbb{E}\|X-Y\|^2} = \sqrt{\mathbb{E}\|Z\|^2}=\sigma \sqrt{d}.
$$
So I am wondering if there are better bounds known for this specific case in the literature of optimal transport. Please point me to these references if it's already a well studied problem.

Comment: If you do not allow your bound to depend on the centers, you will not be able to improve it, as for the case $\theta_1 = ... = \theta_k$ the bound is equal to $W_2(P, Q)$.

Comment: @Steve: That's a good point. Do you think it's possible to make the bound depend on the centers?

Comment: What your current bound does is to transport each mixture component to its center. An easy improvement would be to pair the components in groups of 2 and transport each pair optimally to the two respective centers (this should still be doable analytically). This would yield a slight but noticeably improvement. I'm not sure if that's the best thing to do though.

Comment: @Steve: Can you explain a bit about what you mean by pairing the centers and transporting them optimally?

Comment: Your bound uses just $W^2_2(\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^k \mu_i, \frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^k \nu_i) \leq \frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^k W_2^2(\mu_i, \nu_i)$. An improvement would be $W^2_2(\frac{1}{2k}\sum_{i=1}^{2k} \mu_i, \frac{1}{2k}\sum_{i=1}^{2k} \nu_i) \leq \frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^{k} W_2^2(0.5 (\mu_{2i-1}+\mu_{2i}), 0.5(\nu_{2i-1} + \nu_{2i}))$, where I think the term $W_2^2(0.5 (\mu_{2i-1}+\mu_{2i}), 0.5(\nu_{2i-1} + \nu_{2i}))$ can still be calculated analytically in your case. Just to be clear, in your case $\mu_i = \mathcal{N}(\theta_i, \sigma^2 I_d)$ and $\nu_i = \delta_{\theta_i}$.

Comment: @Steve: Thanks for the explanation. As far as I know, Wasserstein loss between even two mixtures of Gaussians can't be calculated analytically.